# Manipulating DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks likeso; Category1-Category6 are the names of the indices, Jan-2021 and Feb-2021 are the columns:

```
          Jan-2021   Feb-2021
Category1 34565345   58930202
Category2 45213056   37328292
Category3 99658453   42243222
Category4 23455436   35738292
Category5 84384954   34839202
Category6 67932022   34587293
```

I would like it to look likeso, ie double each column under and keep the resulting two columns under the same header. Then lag one duplicate column against the other. Could someone please help?

```
                Jan-2021           Feb-2021           
Category1 34565345            58930202
Category2 45213056  34565345  37328292 58930202
Category3 99658453  45213056  42243222 37328292
Category4 23455436  99658453  35738292 42243222
Category5 84384954  23455436  34839202 35738292
Category6 67932022  84384954  34587293 34839202
                    67932022           34587293
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), but for avoid removing last row is added empty DataFrame, then join both by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and for avoid duplicated columns names is used `keys` parameter, last for expected order use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with convert output to [`integers with NaNs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) if necessary:

```
cols = df.columns
df1 = df.append(pd.DataFrame(index=['new'], columns=cols)).shift()
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1, keys=('orig','lag'))

new = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([cols, ('orig','lag')]).swaplevel(1,0)


df = df.reindex(new, axis=1).astype('Int64')
print (df)
               orig       lag      orig       lag
           Jan-2021  Jan-2021  Feb-2021  Feb-2021
Category1  34565345      <NA>  58930202      <NA>
Category2  45213056  34565345  37328292  58930202
Category3  99658453  45213056  42243222  37328292
Category4  23455436  99658453  35738292  42243222
Category5  84384954  23455436  34839202  35738292
Category6  67932022  84384954  34587293  34839202
new            <NA>  67932022      <NA>  34587293
```

For select in `MultiIndex` is one option use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (df.xs('Jan-2021', axis=1, level=1))
               orig       lag
Category1  34565345      <NA>
Category2  45213056  34565345
Category3  99658453  45213056
Category4  23455436  99658453
Category5  84384954  23455436
Category6  67932022  84384954
new            <NA>  67932022
```

If order of `MultiIndex` levels need swapped:

```
cols = df.columns
df1 = df.append(pd.DataFrame(index=['new'], columns=cols)).shift()
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1, keys=('orig','lag')).swaplevel(1,0, axis=1)

new = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([cols, ('orig','lag')])

df = df.reindex(new, axis=1).astype('Int64')
print (df)
           Jan-2021            Feb-2021          
               orig       lag      orig       lag
Category1  34565345      <NA>  58930202      <NA>
Category2  45213056  34565345  37328292  58930202
Category3  99658453  45213056  42243222  37328292
Category4  23455436  99658453  35738292  42243222
Category5  84384954  23455436  34839202  35738292
Category6  67932022  84384954  34587293  34839202
new            <NA>  67932022      <NA>  34587293


print (df.xs('Jan-2021', axis=1))
               orig       lag
Category1  34565345      <NA>
Category2  45213056  34565345
Category3  99658453  45213056
Category4  23455436  99658453
Category5  84384954  23455436
Category6  67932022  84384954
new            <NA>  67932022
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
import pandas as pd
import io

table = """
 Jan-2021 Feb-2021
Category1 34565345 58930202
Category2 45213056 37328292
Category3 99658453 42243222
Category4 23455436 35738292
Category5 84384954 34839202
Category6 67932022 34587293
"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(table), index_col=0, sep=' ')
df = df.append(pd.Series(name='Category7', index=df.columns))

df['Jan-2021_shifted'] = df['Jan-2021'].shift()
df['Feb-2021_shifted'] = df['Feb-2021'].shift()
df = df[['Jan-2021','Jan-2021_shifted','Feb-2021','Feb-2021_shifted']]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Jan-2021', ''), ('Jan-2021', ''), ('Feb-2021', ''), ('Feb-2021', '')])
print(df)
```

This is what was required:

```
             Jan-2021                Feb-2021            

Category1  34565345.0         NaN  58930202.0         NaN
Category2  45213056.0  34565345.0  37328292.0  58930202.0
Category3  99658453.0  45213056.0  42243222.0  37328292.0
Category4  23455436.0  99658453.0  35738292.0  42243222.0
Category5  84384954.0  23455436.0  34839202.0  35738292.0
Category6  67932022.0  84384954.0  34587293.0  34839202.0
Category7         NaN  67932022.0         NaN  34587293.0
```